# Swift function to return multiple types

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a utility function called `makePostBuilder` which looks something like this.

```swift
fileprivate func makePostRequest(apiUrl: String, params: [String: String]) -> URLRequest? {
        // build url
        let urlString = "\(apiUrl)"
        guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: urlString) else { return nil }
        
        // build url request
        var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        //set http body for url request with incoming params
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: []) else {
            return nil 
        }
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        return request
    }
```

The return type of this function is obviously incorrect. I would like it to either return a `URLRequest` instance OR an `Error` instance. The error instance is mainly so the optional unwrapping can return a valuable message instead of just `nil` (as per the current implementation.

I was thinking along the lines of a `typealias`, but I am not sure if that is the right approach.

```swift
//not sure if this is right
typealias CustomRequestType = (URLRequest, Error)
```

At the end of the appropriate type definitions, I would like the function to look something like this

```swift
fileprivate func makePostRequest(apiUrl: String, params: [String:String]) -> CustomType {
  let urlString = apiUrl
  guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: urlString) else { return //error based on customtype? }

  // build url request
  var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
  request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  //set http body for url request with incoming params
  guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: []) else {
    return //error type 
  }

  //return success type
  request.httpBody = httpBody
  return request
}
```

I think I'm getting close, but not quite there yet. I'd also love if the community could point me to some docs!

**UPDATE: Possible Solution?**

```swift
//does this seem plausible?

enum DCError: String, Error {
    case invalidUrl = "the url seems to be invalid"
}

typealias DCUrlRequestType = Result<URLRequest, Error>

fileprivate func makePostRequest(apiUrl: String, params: Dictionary<String, String>) -> DCUrlRequestType {
    let urlString = apiUrl
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return DCUrlRequestType.failure(DCError.invalidUrl)
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    return DCUrlRequestType.success(request)
}
```

Comment: You can use something like [Result<Success, Failure>](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result). More generally, I you'd need an enum with associated values instead of a tuple

Comment: I've updated the post with a possible answer @NewDev. Let me know if that's on the right path?

Comment: I'd go with @NewDev's path, using something like 
```typealias CustomRequestType = Result<URLRequest, Error>``` then return using ```.success()``` or ```.failure()```

Comment: That gives me a compiler error. `use of undeclared type T`?

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in `enum Result` you can use as your return type. And you can use `URLError(code: .badURL)` (provided by Foundation) in the case where you can't create the `URL`. Thus:

```
fileprivate func makePostRequest(apiUrl: String, params: [String: String]) -> Result<URLRequest, Error> {
    let urlString = "\(apiUrl)"
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return .failure(URLError(.badURL))
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    } catch {
        return .failure(error)
    }
    return .success(request)
}
```

### BUT…

The natural way to write this function is to declare that it `throws`, like this:

```
fileprivate func makePostRequest(apiUrl: String, params: [String: String]) throws -> URLRequest? {
    let urlString = "\(apiUrl)"
    guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {
        throw URLError(.badURL)
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    return request
}
```

and then let the caller use `do/catch` if she wants to handle the error, instead of making the caller switch over the `Result` cases.

If the caller really wants a `Result`, she can use the `Result(catching:)` initializer, which (with trailing closure syntax) looks like this:

```
let requestResult = Result { try makePostRequest(apiUrl: urlString, params: [:]) }
```

Comment: On the other hand (I know you know this), if you _do_ pass a Result, its `get` method turns it into a do/catch at the far end, so there is no need to example the `success` and `failure` explicitly. If `makePostRequest` were itself asynchronous — which, one might argue, it should be — then a completion handler that passes a Result would be the way to go.